# Java ZipFileSystem attributes

Tags: java, copy, filesystems, zip, file-permissions

So I am using a code VERY similar to the following (pulled from http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html):

```
/**
 * Creates/updates a zip file.
 * @param zipFilename the name of the zip to create
 * @param filenames list of filename to add to the zip
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void create(String zipFilename, String... filenames)
    throws IOException {

  try (FileSystem zipFileSystem = createZipFileSystem(zipFilename, true)) {
    final Path root = zipFileSystem.getPath("/");

    //iterate over the files we need to add
    for (String filename : filenames) {
      final Path src = Paths.get(filename);

      //add a file to the zip file system
      if(!Files.isDirectory(src)){
        final Path dest = zipFileSystem.getPath(root.toString(),
                                                src.toString());
        final Path parent = dest.getParent();
        if(Files.notExists(parent)){
          System.out.printf("Creating directory %s\n", parent);
          Files.createDirectories(parent);
        }
        Files.copy(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      }
      else{
        //for directories, walk the file tree
        Files.walkFileTree(src, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>(){
          @Override
          public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
              BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            final Path dest = zipFileSystem.getPath(root.toString(),
                                                    file.toString());
            Files.copy(file, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
          }

          @Override
          public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir,
              BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            final Path dirToCreate = zipFileSystem.getPath(root.toString(),
                                                           dir.toString());
            if(Files.notExists(dirToCreate)){
              System.out.printf("Creating directory %s\n", dirToCreate);
              Files.createDirectories(dirToCreate);
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I call the Files.copy() in the visitFile() method, the src has 'rwxr-xr-x' file permissions, and the dest is successfully created. When I unzip the result, the corresponding file has only 'rw-r--r--' permissions. I tried using

```
Files.copy(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

but the file still has 'rw-r--r--' permissions... Doing a Files.create() with 'rwxr-xr-x' permissions set has the same result... Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried the following, but i just get an UnsupportedOperationException:

```
Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxr-xr-x");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dest, permissions);
```

Comment: I've noticed that the files you store in the `ZipFileSystem` might replace existing files.  The implementation of file updates in the zfs is not very scalable -- it may cache the entire new file in memory until the zfs is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ZIP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) by default does not support Unix filesystem features. And the [ZIP filesystem provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) does at least not support to store Unix file permissions.

```
// ZIP created with teh Java zipfs
zipinfo foobar.zip

file system or operating system of origin:      MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT
version of encoding software:                   2.0
...
non-MSDOS external file attributes:             000000 hex
MS-DOS file attributes (00 hex):                none
```

If you create the ZIP file with the Linux version of the Info-ZIP implementation.

```
file system or operating system of origin:      Unix
version of encoding software:                   3.0
...
apparent file type:                             text
Unix file attributes (100755 octal):            -rwxr-xr-x
MS-DOS file attributes (00 hex):                none
```

For more information you might have a look into the source of `ZipFileSystem.java` [original source](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sherman/zipfs_src/) or from the current included in [JDK 8 Demos and Samples](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

**edit** <s>You could try [TrueVFS](https://truevfs.java.net/index.html) instead of the `zipfs`. After a quick check it seems it also do not support the Unix file permissions.</s>

You could use [Apache commons compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/). Following the javadoc it supports Unix permissions.

from [ZipArchiveEntry.setUnixMode](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-1.10/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveEntry.html#setUnixMode(int))

> Sets Unix permissions in a way that is understood by Info-Zip's unzip
>   command.

Comment: I understand why zip doesnt support unix-specific flags, but it's still VERY annoying..... Do you know of any libs that do support unix-specific flags?